# What are reasons for Channel disconnected message error popup?

Tags: php, apache-flex

While I am testing my application, I find out every time I after update the data to the database. A annoying fault message is popup.

Which is said

> Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received

I check the database, test the php script, check the network monitor, even rewrite the service caller (dont know what its name)

```
<dataservice:DataService id="dataservice2" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail  + '\n' + 'dataservice')" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

And even create a new application just to test that component. But, every things are working and the database had received correct data set and I still cannot Identity where that message is come form.

How can I find the source of this message???

Comment: Could you provide a few more details about the architecture and where and when is the error pop up being displayed.  Also what kinds of components or package or other software is being used?  Is this posting describing your problem?  http://www.designovermatter.com/post.cfm/flex-error-channel-disconnected-before-an-acknowledgement-was-received

Comment: Or how about this posting.  http://akcora.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/flex-php-channel-disconnected-before-an-acknowledgement-was-received-error/

Comment: Also this stack overflow posting provides a possible approach.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140902/deploying-flex-php-application-on-server-channel-disconnected

Comment: My application still in the development evironment. so the domain should not be a problem.

Comment: And this posting describes some basic troubleshooting steps to ensure the interface between your flex and your php are similar.  http://flextutorial4you.blogspot.com/2011/04/clienterrordeliveryindoubt-channel.html

Comment: And this stack overflow describes changing the message to something else.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519762/flex-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-channel-disconnected-error-message

Comment: I find it,[04-Nov-2012 12:17:51] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\fypweee_admin\FYPadminSideV3-debug\services\StockproductService.php on line 238

Meaning??

Comment: Take a look at these stackoverflow postings.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967597/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference

Comment: Thanks, I know where is the error come form. ps. it is so funny that php said dont want to pass by reference, but it still pass the data to the database, lol.

Comment: could you provide an answer describing what you found and how you solved it?

Comment: OK,  I will post the answer when I solve the referenceing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error cause by the PHP script. While I look at the PHP error log file, I found out Flex is not displaying the variable reference error which is like this

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\fypweee_admin\FYPadminSideV3-debug\services\StockproductService.php on line 238
```

If you are using XAMPP, the error log file will be at `[your hard disk name]:\xampp\php\logs1`.

Since the php script still mysteriously dispatch the data set to the database and I think I will leave that error (for now).

Answer (score 0):

1.put the folders inside your project

```
   (i).flex-spreadsheet(folder)
   (ii).amfphp-spreadsheet(folder)
```

2.Then open the file

```
  for xamp=> \htdocs\projectname\flex-spreadsheet\properties\ApplicationSettings.properties

  for wamp=> \www\projectname\flex-spreadsheet\properties\ApplicationSettings.properties
```

3.Make the first line as

```
serverpath=http://192.xxx.x.xxx/projectname/amfphp-spreadsheet/gateway.php
**or**
serverpath=localhost/projectname/amfphp-spreadsheet/gateway.php
```

This works for me.